# Ways to process data which is coming at double speed than my processing speed

Tags: c++, multithreading

I was asked this question my someone and bit confused on same.

Q: how will you process the data which is coming at double speed than my processing speed?

I think of following:

1. using queue to handle this. But if I use simply  queue then size of
   queue required will be indefinetly large and i will still lag
   behind. As every t time i will have half more data that I can
   process. and I will keep laging exponentially.
2. I use one thread for reading data and two more for processing. But
   suppose my data has to be processed serially then what happens.

Am still confused and any help on similar problems will be welcomed. I know there might be a standard solution for this but am unaware of same.

I would like to implement in c/c++

Comment: It is unclear what 'processing speed' means. If it means ALL your processing speed including all threads and processors in your system, then there is no solution, the system will choke. You will have to drop some data. But if processing speed can be parallelled, you will have to use a queue of incoming tasks and a queue of outgoing results. Both queues will be used by a thread pool. Again, if the data has to be processed serially then the queues will block so you will not be able to parallelize it and the system will choke again.

Comment: It might be useful to know where your data comes from because different sources might offer different solutions. For example if you get your data from the internet like a webserver then you could load balance several machines.

Comment: This is very unclear and does not make sense in places.  If you are going to queue the work to multiple threads, (so they can execute in parallel on different cores), the intent would be to speed up overall work processing so that the 'infinite queue' is no longer an issue.  If it is still possible that the system might get overloaded with work ,then you have to make a decision on flow-control, either dumping input or throttling it.  Need more details, as @TorbenJonas says.

Comment: The 'serial processing' requirement may, or may not be a problem.  For instance, you may be able to sequence-number the data before queueing it and then re-serialize it afterwards.  More details!

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: you'll need some kind of *parallel processing*. It's not easy.

Long answer: Depending on your workload requirements, and whether the bottleneck is in IO or in CPU, it might simply be multithreading on a single core, or on a multicore processor, or on a shared memory multiprocessor or even distributed between multiple nodes. It can be just a matter of distributing and balancing your work between the worker units, if the problem is simple enough (*embarrasingly parallel*) or you'll need to explicitly do some *parallel programming*. There are fundamentally two parallel programming models: OpenMP, for multithreading in multicore systems with shared memory (either symmetric or non-uniform access); and MPI, for distributed processing in a low-latency high-bandwidth network. To complicate even further, OpenMP and MPI might perfectly run together, in a hybrid parallel programming runtime environment: OpenMP distributes and coordinates the parallel compute load between the cores on each node, and MPI does it between the nodes. Be aware, it is very tough work.